# QTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread

Tags: multithreading, qt, post

So I have an interesting problem....a program I am (trying) to write is crashing with this error:

```
QObject::startTimer: QTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread
```

The thing that baffles me is my program is single threaded.  The goal of the class in question is to send POST data to a php page I have on my server.  As soon as it tries to send the POST, I get that message.  Here is my code.

```
#ifndef TRANSMISSIONS_H
#define TRANSMISSIONS_H
#include "name_spawn.h"
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QObject>
#include <QNetworkConfigurationManager>

class Transmissions : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Transmissions();
    void Send(GeneratedData);
public slots:
    void serviceRequestFinished(QNetworkReply*);
signals:
    void configurationAdded(const QNetworkConfiguration);
    void configurationChanged(const QNetworkConfiguration);
    void configurationRemoved(const QNetworkConfiguration);
    void onlineStateChanged(bool);
    void updateCompleted();
};

#endif // TRANSMISSIONS_H
```

And

```
#include "transmissions.h"
#include "name_spawn.h"
#include <QHttp>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QString>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <iostream>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkConfigurationManager>
#include <QObject>

using namespace std;

Transmissions::Transmissions()
{
}

void Transmissions::Send(GeneratedData User)
{
    cerr<<"transmitting"<<endl;
    QUrl serviceUrl = QUrl("http://192.168.1.138/postTest.php");
    QByteArray postData;
    QString username="user="+User.Email()+"&";
    QString Passwd="password="+User.pass();
    postData.append(username);
    postData.append(Passwd);

    QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(serviceRequestFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
    networkManager->post(QNetworkRequest(serviceUrl), postData);
}

void Transmissions::serviceRequestFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    //this will do other things once post is working
    QString data = reply->readAll();
    cerr <<"Data is "<< data.toStdString()<<endl;

}
```

I think what I am trying to do is fairly simple, but it is frustrating me to no end trying to get it to work.  I didn't see anything in the documentation about QNetworkAccessManager  requiring threads.  I admit I don't know Qt that well, so any help (or links to complete POST examples) would be very appreciated.

Comment: Are you running a Qt event loop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To use a `QTimer` you need to have an event loop. QNAM obviously uses a timer to periodically check for the network reply.

You need to start the application event loop with `QCoreApplication::exec()` and then call QNAM methods like `post` after that.

I think you can call `post` before `exec` but you may come across [this bug](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.general/41451).

Also, note that up to Qt 4.7 QNAM did not use threading but with 4.8 [this is changing](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/04/29/threaded-http-inside-qnetworkaccessmanager/).

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  Like I told synthesizerpatel, I wont be able to test this until Sunday though.  Should I assume that QCoreApplication::exec() should be run through my programs main rather than in the Transmission class?

Comment: Yes, normally the last line of `main` is simply `return app.exec()`.

Comment: So far that error has not come up, but I can confirm post is working!  Thank you very much Troubadour.  If I could upvote your answer more than once I would :)

Comment: This answered my question which was slightly different. I was trying to start a QTimer in a class constructor instantiated in my main() before the event loop had been started.

Comment: This also solved my issue with having QTest, a separate main (executing multiple tests via qExec) and those tests having timers. I added "QCoreApplication app(argc,argv)" and now the test works and no errors are getting thrown.

Answer (score 1):

This may be related to creating the QNetworkAccessManager inside the Send method - try instead using RAII.

Define the QNetworkAccessManager in the header for Transmissions as a class variable, and create a class instance it in the ctor, then you will be able to post to it from the Send thread.

Otherwise I think it goes out of scope.

Comment: I wont be able to test this for a few days, but I'll let you know if it works by Sunday.  I don't quite understand how networkManager would go out of scope if its used in the same method it was declared in.  Could you explain that?  "you will be able to post to it from the Send thread"  Far as I know my program isn't even using threads.  Did QNetworkAccessManager create one somewhere?

Comment: The scope of QNAM is only within the 'send' method - once that method is done, that object is gone (Unless you create a class variable/class instance of it. If you create it as a class variable and create an instance in the ctor, then it'll be around after 'send' has run, and will be able to respond to / send signals. See http://www.java2s.com/Code/Cpp/Qt/DownloadfromURL.htm

Comment: The pointer goes out of scope, not the object. The object is parented to the Transmission instance so will get deleted when that is destroyed.

Comment: Correct, the pointer goes out of scope. Bad explanation on my part, but the solution is still correct.

Comment: Gentlemen, I thank you both.  +1 for synthesizerpatel for that link as well.

Comment: I'm still trying to get my head around one thing. I know when Send finishes its run that QNAM goes out of scope.  From the way I am reading the code (and I probably just dont know enough about signals to get this right), wouldn't networkManager->post send the data to the webserver, call serviceRequestFinished and then return all the way back to the send method before it finished and rendered the pointer out of scope?

Comment: Signals are asynchronous, since the response to your query may not ever come back (website is down, dns doesn't resolve, etc).. this allows the rest of your app to continue running without blocking on that request (or any http request) - if your app blocked and waited, the whole UI would freeze up.

Comment: -1: No idea who removed my second comment so let me be more assertive. This answer is completely wrong. The pointer going out of scope affects nothing. The QNAM created will have the same lifetime as the Transmission object. The only issue here is that a new QNAM is created on each call to `post` which is wasteful but it doesn't make the slightest difference to the problem at hand.