# Using QTimer from non-Qt DLL (JNA)

Tags: java, c++, qt, jna, qt-mfc-migration

I wrote a library (DLL).
Java code uses my DLL with JNA.
In library I creates Qtimer by "new" in QThread derived class.

But, I have the following error:

```
ERROR: QTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread
```

How should I properly use QTimer to invoke from non-Qt thread without QApplication/QCoreApplication?

Comment: i think the obvious answer is that you cannot... but if you don`t trust me read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450044/qtimer-can-only-be-used-with-threads-started-with-qthread

Comment: But, I don't have QCoreApplication. Should I need to create QCoreApplication instance?

Comment: quotation from the link i gave you: "To use a QTimer you need to have an event loop. You need to start the application event loop with QCoreApplication::exec()."

Comment: Where is I need to start app event loop? What place in code?

Comment: Given that ::exec() does not return, at a minimum you'd need to call it from a dedicated (Java) thread.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately QTimer requires QCoreApplication as far as I know. And also QCoreApplication must be instantiated in the thread that creates the first QObject I see. What I did was to instantiate QCoreApplication a new thread spawned using [QtConcurrent::run](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentrun.html#run), and instantiated my QObjects in there. I reported a trivial example [here](http://thebugfreeblog.blogspot.it/2012/05/embedded-cross-platform-development-for.html). QTimer now seems to be working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`QBasicTimer`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbasictimer.html). I'm not 100% sure if this will work but at least the documentation doesn't mention `QThread`s and event loops at all (in contrast to the documentation of the [`QTimer`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QTimer.html) class).

The drawback is that it's a bit more complicated (it calls `timerEvent()` reimplementation in your `QObject`, no signal-slot-connection), but if it's true, you can use it without an event loop.