# Error in networking application with python and PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm developing a networking application with python and PyQt4 and i'm getting the following error:

> QObject::startTimer: QTimer can only be used with threads started with
>   QThread QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents: Cannot send posted events
>   for objects in another thread QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps
>   outside the GUI thread QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside
>   the GUI thread

Please suggest a way to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450044/qtimer-can-only-be-used-with-threads-started-with-qthread

Comment: post your code we cant help if we cant see it